# How to change Primary Key Columns in Integer to Varchar For tables Containing Live Data

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a central SQL Sever 2008 Database which is supposed to collate data from individual databases with the same structure as the central database. Now most of the tables in the client databases have integer primary key columns, thus, migrating data to the central database from the client databases isn't possible.

My theory for the solution I have in mind is to change the primary key columns from integer to varchar, so data submission to the server is seamless. But I need to be able to do this so the data already entered in the client databases are not affected or lost.

Can someone help me out of this challenge? Quick help will be appreciate. Thanks alot.

Comment: If you have duplicate keys among client databases, changing from integer to varchar won't help. You'll just have duplicate varchars instead of duplicate integers. [This sounds like an XY issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161666). What's the *real* problem?

Comment: `most of the tables in the client databases have integer primary key columns, thus, migrating data [...] isn't possible` --> care to elaborate on this?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The real problem here is I need to be able to handle migration of data from all individual databases straight to the central server. My theory may not be right. Could you suggest something better?